# Capture output in console (nice & tidy) and write it to word file

Tags: r, reporters

I am trying to export R output table to word file. I am using `ReporteRs` package to do this. I capture the output and pass it to a paragraph. In this approach, the tidy output gets distorted and doesn't look nice as it was in console or when saved to a text file. How do I pass the output as is to word file? Thank you in advance.

```
    data("cars2")
    mydoc = docx(title = "Summary")
    library(gmodels)
    aal<-capture.output(CrossTable(cars2$Country, cars2$Type, digits=2, chisq=T))
    #capture.output(CrossTable(cars2$Country, cars2$Type, digits=2, chisq=T, format="SPSS"), file="tests.txt")
    mydoc<-addParagraph( mydoc, aal)
    writeDoc( mydoc, file = "Summary.docx")
```

Comment: I can use `capture.output(CrossTable(cars2$Country, cars2$Type, digits=2, chisq=T, format="SPSS"), file="tests.doc")` to save the output directly to a word file. However, by this way I won't be able to use other useful functions from `ReporteRs`. I am using a word template and do export graphs and other objects to word file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a monospace font (as R console output is using monospace font)

```
library(gmodels)
data(infert, package = "datasets")
xx=capture.output(CrossTable(infert$education, infert$induced, expected = TRUE, format="SPSS"))
```

**Solution 1:** use an existing style (from your template) that is using a monospaced font, i.e `rRawOutput` in the default template

```
library( ReporteRs )
mydoc <- docx(title = "Summary")
mydoc <- addParagraph( mydoc, xx, stylename = "rRawOutput" )
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "Summary.docx")
```

---

**Solution 2:** use `pot` function to create a piece of text with a specified monospace font

```
library( ReporteRs )    
mydoc <- docx(title = "Summary")
mypot <- pot( paste(xx, collapse = "\n"), 
      format = textProperties(font.family = "Courier New", font.size = 9) )
mydoc <- addParagraph( mydoc, mypot,  par.properties = parLeft() )
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "Summary.docx")
```

---

**Solution 3**: this one does not really answer your question as it does not use gmodels but I like the output:

```
library( ReporteRs )
library( rtable )
library( broom )

data(infert, package = "datasets")
myft = freqtable(table(infert$education, infert$induced))
ct = chisq.test(infert$education, infert$induced)

mydoc = docx(title = "Summary")
mydoc = addTitle(mydoc, "Table", level = 2)
mydoc = addFlexTable( mydoc, myft )
mydoc = addTitle(mydoc, "Chi-squared Test", level = 2)
mydoc = addFlexTable( mydoc, vanilla.table( tidy(ct) ) )
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "Summary.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very-well elaborated answer. Your package `ReporteRs` rocks! Keep up your good work!